# How to configure PocketBeagle CAN Connection to a vehicle?

Tags: linux, beagleboard, can-bus

We are currently experimenting with the PocketBeagle CAN Connection but haven't had much success yet. The PocketBeagle will be connected to a vehicle. To accomplish this we use a CAN Board (https://www.waveshare.com/sn65hvd230-can-board.htm) in connection with a step down converter and an OBD2 Male Connector.

Our first thought was that we can use the dcan1 Pins (P2.09 for RX, P2.11 for TX), so we configured the pins to function as CAN Connectors.

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ config-pin P2_09 can
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ config-pin P2_11 can
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 125000
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ sudo ifconfig can0 up
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9$ candump can0
```

However, we don't get any data back. What can we do to solve this problem?

We then tried different tutorials:

http://www.thomas-wedemeyer.de/beaglebone-canbus-python.html
http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Beaglebone-CAN-Bus-Cape/

They didn't work either.

Another problem is that there is almost no documentation on how to use the PocketBeagle CAN or maybe we just can't find it.

We are really thankful for any advice or solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic answer to see what you could achieve: if you connect to P2_09 & P2_11 you need to configure and activate CAN1

I'm working on the same issue: trying to monitor a CAN bus to filter out messages that interest me.